# send sms without inputting contact number

Tags: android

i already know the code how to send sms by typing the number and the message, but what i want to know is it possible to send message only without typing the contact number?  Here’s my situation, im working at water district, I’m making app for reporting leak thru text, what i want to happen is, the reporter is only need to type the message then send, without inputting the number. We only have 1 hotline number, so I don’t think the reporter need to type the contact number everytime the reporter text us, he just need to type the message then click send only.

Comment: you can store the number in SharedPreferences and access it

Comment: Man did u find my answer useful..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> send sms without inputting contact number

Following code works without inputting the number again and again. The `address` attribute stores the number(hotline number) and When user clicks on report it default takes you to messaging app with number already stored and allow to write the text and go.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms/");
intent.putExtra("address", your_hotline_number);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", " ");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Make sure u put number inside quotes "0123456789" like wise. It should be in string format.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the recipient number in a constant field as

```
public static final String recipientNo = "*********";
```

Then if you use implicit `intent` the add below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + recipientNo));     
intent.putExtra("sms_body", message); 
startActivity(intent);
```

or if you use `SmsManager`,

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

and add permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's working for me:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", "12345", null)));
```

Comment: 12345 is sms receiver number